# How can I use the Values gem with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, gemfile

Gemfile:

```
gem 'values'
```

Also tried Gemfile:

```
gem 'values', require: 'values'
```

Gemfile.lock

```
values (1.8.0)
```

$ bundle install

```
Using values 1.8.0
```

But $ rails console

```
> Value

NameError (uninitialized constant Value)

> require 'values'

LoadError (cannot load such file -- values)
```

But if I just $ irb

```
require 'values'

=> true
```

How can I get to the Value object in rails?

Comment: try running console as `bundle exec rails console`

Comment: 'bundle exec rails console' gives the same errors.

Comment: Weird, should have worked. (Tried on my machine, works here)

Comment: Strange. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Previously I faced such problem for `awesome_print` gem, the issue is due to `spring` preloader.

First, you need to stop `spring` from a terminal using the following command.

```
spring stop
```

Then restart your rails console.

Hope this will help for you.